# MVC3 Editing Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, null

I have the following Model.

```
 public class Person
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType("Users")]
    [Display(Name = "Adresse")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
```

As you can see, it contains a public Field of Address Type:

```
    public class Address
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Rue")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Ville")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Province")]
    public string Province { get; set; }
```

I have no problem creating a new instance. Both the person and the address are posted into the database

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Persons.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

I would like to understand why when I retrieve the Person from the db using the following commands, the Address is always NULL.

```
 return db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to eager load the address property.

```
return db.Persons.Include("Address").FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need lazy loading behavior you need to mark `Address` property as virtual

```
[Required]
[DataType("Users")]
[Display(Name = "Adresse")]
public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eranga, I will try this out today.